# sumifs on multiple colums to be pasted on different sheet

Tags: excel, sumifs

```
person  value  month         y/n

Matt    300    October       y

Matt    50     October       y

Peter   100    October       y

Peter   400    October       y

Sheila  20     October       y

Sheila  70     October       y

James   100    November      y

James   120    November      y

Piece   50     October       n

Piece   150     October       n
```

Hi everyone,

I have to apply sumifs for the above hypothetical data( it is a much larger database). The sumifs result has to be copied in a different cell on a different sheet.

I have this so far

```
=(sumifs('sheet1'!$F$3:$F$1000),('sheet1'!$D$3:$D$1000,"Matt"),('sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1000,"October"),('sheet1'!$J$3:$J$1000,"Y"))
```

But i am getting an error. Am I missing some condition at the end? (Like does Y have to be equal or true statement is missing)?

Answer (score 1):

Try losing a few brackets.

```
=sumifs('sheet1'!$F$3:$F$1000, 'sheet1'!$D$3:$D$1000, "Matt", 'sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1000, "October", 'sheet1'!$J$3:$J$1000, "Y")
'I see no reason why you couldn't use full column references
=sumifs('sheet1'!F:F, 'sheet1'!D:D, "Matt", 'sheet1'!G:G, "October", 'sheet1'!J:J, "Y")
```

Yes, you can use two criteria with OR operation inside a string literal array but you have to wrap the whole sumifs in sum.

```
=sum(sumifs('North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$F$2:$F$400,
            'North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$D$2:$D$400,  {"Sri", "Aanchal/Sri"} ,
            'North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$G$2:$G$400, "October",
            'North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$J$2:$J$400, "Y"))
```

Comment: I can't use full columns as been advised not to. Used the above approach but now from !error get  #NA. Also why did you suggest removing the Dollar sign($)?

Comment: What ampersand ? I honestly see no ampersand.

Comment: If you aren't going to copy or drag the formula sideways to another cell they are completely unnecessary. What possible advantage does fixed ranges give over full column references? If there actually is a calculation benefit (and I doubt there is), it would be so small as to be unmeasurable. Conversely, if your range changes, you have to rewrite all your formulas with fixed ranges.

Comment: Yeah, but i mentioned in the question that I need to copy the result of the sum on a different cell on a different sheet. Fixed ranges is what is needed since there would be no more data will be added.

Comment: ... and you shouldn't be getting #N/A errors with a sumifs, even if there were #N/A errors in the data.

Comment: SUMIFS expects all arguments after position 3 to be in pairs. this is the #NA error coming

Comment: First pair `'sheet1'!$D$3:$D$1000, "Matt"` Second pair `'sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1000, "October"` third pair `'sheet1'!$J$3:$J$1000, "Y"`. Again, I fail to see the issue.

Comment: Nope, still not working. this is the actual sumifs statement i am using

(sumifs('North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$F$2:$F$400,'North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$D$2:$D$400, "Sri", "Aanchal/Sri" ,'North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19'!$G$2:$G$400, "October",'North - Delhi NCR-2018 - 19'!$J$2:$J400, "Y"))

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious you have two text criteria for the first criteria range. That's not impossible but it isn't what you asked.

Comment: Also, the last 'North - Delhi NCR- 2018 - 19' may be missing a space and `$J$2:$J400` is missing a **$**.

Comment: so that's the only case where there is two text criteria, apart from that there is only one text criteria.

Comment: Yeah, still getting the #NA error SUMIFS expects all arguments after position 3 to be in pairs.